# How to make discord bot disconnect user from voice chat?

Tags: python

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
import random
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix= '+')

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('We have logged in as {0.user}'.format(client))
    await client.change_presence(status=discord.Status.offline)

@client.command()
async def kick(ctx, member : discord.Member):
    await member.disconnect()

client.run(<TOKEN>)
```

I want to make a commands that disconnect target from voice chat what should i use or do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Member.move_to](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.move_to) and pass None to it to remove someone from a voice channel.